# this sql query works in mysql but not in mssql

Tags: mysql, sql-server

mysql:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (select * from songs order by artist asc) as songs2 
WHERE artist LIKE 'a%' GROUP BY artist`
```

mssql:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (select top 1000 * from songs order by artist asc) as songs2  
WHERE artist LIKE 'a%' GROUP BY artist
```

This works in mysql but in mssql i get an error:

> Column 'songs2.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not
>   contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

++++++++++++++++++
now i select with this query :
SELECT artist,album,song from (select top 1000 * from songs order by year asc, artist asc) as songs2 where artist like 'a%' group by artist,album,song;
but it does not group by artist, i want only one artist per song available in the query

Comment: Do what the error message says and remove the clause. It doesn't really do anything (there's no guarantee that the outer query respects that order, even though it'll probably do it).

Comment: I changed the sql to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will find 1 song per artist and a maximum of 1000 songs:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 
  artist,album,song 
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    artist,album,song, 
    row_number() over (partition by artist order by (SELECT 1)) rn
  FROM table_name 
  WHERE artist like 'a%' 
) as t2 
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

In mysql you can select values which are not in `group by` statement. It is not possible in mssql.

```
SELECT artist FROM 
(
    select * from songs 
) as songs2 
where artist like 'a%' group by artist;
```

And also you can not use order by in a subquery.

Comment: actually you can use ORDER BY in a subquery when combined with TOP on sqlserver

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    select * from songs 
) as songs2 
where artist like 'a%';
```

There is no point to order the rows in the `sub-query` as you are not using `TOP` to get `N` of them, `OFFSET` to apply paging or `FOR XML` to order `XML` nodes.

If you want to order the results, do it in the outer query:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    select * from songs 
) as songs2 
where artist like 'a%'
order by year asc, artist asc;
```

So, basically, you can shorted this:

```
SELECT *  
from songs 
where artist like 'a%' 
order by year asc, artist asc;
```

Comment: ]Column 'songs2.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @shervinkhaleghjoo Remove the `GROUP BY` clause or add all columns in it.

Answer (score 0):

Order By in subquery Require **TOP/OFFSET/FOR XML Cluase**

```
SELECT artist FROM 
(
    select top 100 percent * from songs 
    order by year asc, artist asc
) as songs2 
where artist like 'a%' group by artist;
```

Comment: ]Column 'songs2.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Comment: I want to know the song name also, only artist is not enough